# How does Automatic conversion works in java?

Tags: java

So i had this exercise to add first seven terms from 1 to 7 in order like 1/1!+2/2!+3/3!........7/7!. Below is my code:

```
 public class Problem9 
 {
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
    int num, i;
    float result = 1.0f;
    for(num=2; num<=4; num++)
    {
        i =num;
        int fact_num=1;

        while(i>=1)
        {
            fact_num = i*fact_num;
            i--;
        }
        System.out.println("num = "+num);
        System.out.println("fact = "+fact_num);
        result = result+ (float)num/fact_num;// This line is the one i m   
                                             // talking about
    }
    System.out.printf("The result = %.3f ",result);
   }
  }
```

So what is the difference between following line

```
 result = result+ (float)num/fact_num;
```

and

```
 result = result+ (float)(num/fact_num);
```

How is the conversion working here.

Answer (score 2):

`(float)(num/fact_num)` performs int division and casts the result to float, which means that if `num` < `fact_num`, the result would be 0.0.

`(float)num/fact_num` casts num to float and performs floating point division, which means the result won't be 0.0 if `num` < `fact_num` (unless `num` is 0 of course). This is the form you should use in your code, since you are performing divisions whose results are smaller than 1, so int division won't give you the correct result.

Comment: (float)(num/fact_num) is giving 0 as and therefore the rest of the result is only 2.

Answer (score 1):

```
(float)(num/fact_num);
```

Means the result of the two integer divisions casts into a float. The final answer will be a float.

```
(float)num/fact_num;
```

Here the int `num` is cast into a float. the divided by an integer.

For example :

```
       int num = 5;
       int fact_num = 2;
       System.out.println((float)(num/fact_num));
```

will give an output of:

```
2.0
```